# JQuery .on("click") only firing after second click

Tags: jquery

so I've been trying to animate a menu by clicking on a menu box (similar to Medium's menu). So far everything works, and on a full blown page refresh the JQuery event fires the first time without any problems.

However, when I click on a link in the menu, it'll take me to the page but then the menu button doesn't work on the first click, but it works perfectly fine on the second click. This happens without fail.

I've looked at several other questions similar to this but none of their solutions are solving my problem. Does anyone have any ideas what might be going wrong? Oh, and I'm also using Ruby on Rails 4 if this affects it at all.

Menu Button HTML

```
<div id="menu-hex"></div>
```

Menu HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <%= link_to(root_url) do %>
            <h3 class="am"><span class="icon-home profile-icos"></span> Daily Feed</h3>
        <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="coming-soon">
        <%= link_to(root_url) do %>
            <h3 class="am"><span class="icon-fire profile-icos"></span> Improve</h3>
        <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="coming-soon">
        <%= link_to(root_url) do %>
            <h3 class="am"><span class="icon-star profile-icos"></span> Events</h3>
        <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="coming-soon">
        <%= link_to("/login") do %>
            <h3 class="am"><span class="icon-bookmarks profile-icos"></span> Communities</h3>
        <% end %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu-hex {
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    top: 7px;
    background-image: url('homehex.png');
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    background-size: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
var menuOn = false;
var duration = 250;

$(document).on("click", "#menu-hex", function(e) {
    if(menuOn == false) {
        openMenu();
    }else {
        closeMenu();
    }

});

$(document).on("click", ".overlay", function(e) {
    if(menuOn == true) {
        closeMenu();
    }

});


function openMenu() {

    $(".overlay").css( "display", "block" );

    $("#focusimage").animate({opacity: 0.2}, duration);
    $("#spot-content").animate({"left":"-300px"}, duration, function() 
        { $("#spot-content").css( "display", "none" ) });

    $("#menu").animate({"left":"25px", opacity: 1.0}, duration);

    menuOn = true;
}

function closeMenu() {

    $(".overlay").css( "display", "none" );

    $("#focusimage").animate({opacity: 1.0}, duration);

    $("#spot-content").css( "display", "block");
    $("#spot-content").animate({"left":"25px"}, duration);

    $("#menu").animate({"left":"-300px", opacity: 1.0}, duration);

    menuOn = false;
}
```

Comment: Now, what on earth does `setTimeout(set);` do ?

Comment: I forgot to remove that from something else I was trying haha. Woops.

Comment: Try setting up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

I found out my problem. It's that Rails 4 uses turbolinks. My solution was found here:
[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Answer (score 1):

why are you using:

```
$(document).on("click", ".overlay", function(e) {
    if(menuOn == true) {
        closeMenu();
    }

});
```

instead of:

```
$(".overlay").on("click", function(e) {
    if(menuOn == true) {
        closeMenu();
    }
});
```

?

Comment: Is that your final answer ?

Comment: You should probably read the chapter on delegated event handlers in the documentation !

Comment: You're not doing it wrong, but those two code examples in your answer are both valid, they just do different things. The first one delegates, while the last one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the following block: `$(document).on("click", "#menu-hex", function(e) {
    if(menuOn == false || '')`  The problem is(if i'm not wrong), on the first click after reload, the menuOn variable is unset, so it works only after second click.

Comment: But it's clearly set to false at the top of the script ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to jQuery, but I'm feeling like your script isn't waiting for the document to load.
have you tried surrounding the script with this method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your code

});
```

There might not be a problem with your code, but maybe with the way you are executing it. I hope it helps.

Check this [article](http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/how-to-make-a-smooth-animated-menu-with-jquery/) it might help you.